# How to handle InvalidOperationException inside a catch block

Tags: c#, exception, asynchronous, try-catch, backgroundworker

I have code that uses a BackgroundWorker to read information from an excel sheet and upload it to a database, while also displaying a form that notifies the user of the progress. This is a C# project.

However, in my try/catch statement that reads the excel files and uploads them I want to be able to close the progress form, because there is no use for it any longer.

When I call the .Close() method of the BackgroundWorker class, an InvalidOperationException is fired, and I'm not sure how I can handle this situation. Is there a way to handle it? Is there another way to close the window?

Here is my catch block (located in the `DoWork` event):

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error Uploading Data. See log for details.", "Database Submission Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    // Cancel operation
    backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
    // Close form
    progress.Close();
}
```

backgroundWorker1 is the BackgroundWorker reading/uploading data, and progress is the window that shows the progress bar and count completed/remaining information.

The exception:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'ProgressForm' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Comment: Yes it is, Grant. I'm not sure why I was accused of not reading the exception, or why someone would comment just to tell me I need to fix the bug. Clearly I do, and was unable to figure it out which is why I'm here. The exception reads "An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'ProgressForm' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on." So perhaps I cannot call .Close() within a backgroundWorker1 method? Where should it be?

Comment: Make yourself familiar with the difference between the UI thread and background threads. This is essential to know when doing GUI programming. https://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en&gws_rd=ssl#complete=1&hl=en&q=winforms+threading That should get you started.

Comment: Definitely some valuable resources in there, thanks. I have only been programming C# a couple months, and this was my first project with threading. Simple beginners mistake, so I appreciate the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do anything in the `DoWork` event that touches the UI thread directly, including closing a Form that (I assume) you created before running the thread. Here's a basic "flow" for you to follow:

1. Create a new instance of your progress Form and show it.
2. Start the BackgroundWorker.
3. Do not catch exceptions in the `DoWork` event unless you intend to correct the situation that caused them right then and there. Otherwise, exceptions will stop the worker and fall through to the `RunWorkerCompleted` event, which occurs back on the UI thread.
4. Check `e.Error` in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event... if it's not `null`, then there's an exception and you can take appropriate action such as notifying the user. Because this event is back on the UI thread, you can also close your Form.

Try this: *(written on-the-fly, should compile with a few adjustments)*

```
var progress = new MyProgressForm();
progress.Show();

backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

...
...

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        // log the exception

        MessageBox.Show("Error Uploading Data. See log for details.",
                        "Database Submission Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

        // we're back on the UI thread, so we can touch UI elements
        progress.Close();

        return;
    }

    // stuff to do if no error occurred
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining that. It helped me discover the exceptions that were being thrown (which I did on purpose for testing) could be handled elsewhere, and in turn improved my code because I was able to move from one excel file to the next, even if the first one didn't work. Try/Catch blocks are nasty, I know, but for IO often seem like the best option. Any way, thanks for the help!